# Time Complexity for Asymptotic Functions

Tags: discrete-mathematics, algorithms, asymptotics, solution-verification

Here below I have a problem set where I am asked to define the relationship between f(n) and g(n). I have added in my solutions but I wanted to get my answers checked by you guys before I turn this in. If you could let me know what solutions are wrong and give me an explanation as to why it's wrong that would be great. Thanks!

[image: My answers are on the left side]

PS: My answers are on the left side.

Comment: Is this graded homework?

Comment: For some cases it's better to use $o(\cdot)$ and $\omega(\cdot)$, since e.g. $n! = o(n^n)$.

Comment: Yes, this is graded.

Answer (score 0):

d, h, j look wrong. Also there appears to be a typo in k, because $n$ does not appear in the the formula for $f(n)$. For d, take the ratio and use L'Hoptial's rule to compute the limit as $n \to \infty$. Almost the same with h, take the ratio and then take the limit as $n \to \infty$ (again using L'Hopital if necessary). For j I think you just made a typo.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Yes, J was a typo: it should be O(g). H should be O(g), and D should be theta(g). Let me know what you think, thanks!